# Updating GridView Row from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, code-behind

When the user changes the text in the textbox's in the edit template and clicks update, when I try to grab those new values it still is graving the old value of the text box.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="CompanyID" CellPadding="4"  
        GridLines="None" Width="1079px" ForeColor="#333333" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelling"
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">


        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                        CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CompanyID") %>' Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>


            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue Date">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="IssueDate" Text='<%#Eval("IssueDate") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtIssueDate" Text='<%#Eval("IssueDate") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notice Intent Response Due">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="NoticeIntentResponseDue" Text='<%#Eval("NoticeIntentResponseDue") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNoticeIntentResponseDue" Text='<%#Eval("NoticeIntentResponseDue") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deadline For Questions">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DeadlineForQuestions" Text='<%#Eval("DeadlineForQuestions") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDeadlineForQuestions" Text='<%#Eval("DeadlineForQuestions") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bids Due">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="BidsDue" Text='<%#Eval("BidsDue") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBidsDue" Text='<%#Eval("BidsDue") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shortlist Notice">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShortlistNotice" Text='<%#Eval("ShortlistNotice") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtShortlistNotice" Text='<%#Eval("ShortlistNotice") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Final Selection">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FinalSelection" Text='<%#Eval("FinalSelection") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFinalSelection" Text='<%#Eval("FinalSelection") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>





            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="CompanyID">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CompanyID" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>




        </Columns>



    </asp:GridView>
```

The update button calls this function:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

    {

        int key = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

        Label CompanyID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCompanyID");

        TextBox thisIssueDate = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtIssueDate"));

        TextBox NoticeIntentResponseDue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNoticeIntentResponseDue");

        Response.Write(NoticeIntentResponseDue.Text + " " + thisIssueDate.Text);
        Response.End();

        TextBox DeadlineForQuestions = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDeadlineForQuestions");

        TextBox BidsDue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBidsDue");

        TextBox ShortlistNotice = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtShortlistNotice");

        TextBox FinalSelection = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFinalSelection");
    }
```

The response is showing me that the value being grabbed is still the origonal text value of the box. Not what you typed into the box.

Comment: Where are you binding the GridView? You may want to make sure that you do it inside of `if(!IsPostBack) { }`, as the edit command may trigger a PostBack, and thus rebind the grid to its original values.

Comment: the problem looks like that you have also bind your Edit Item template columns with the data from data table, and when you are getting the data in the code behind you are not getting the updated data which the user updates in edit mode and u still getting the old data.

Comment: run your code without binding the edit item template fields and check your code will work.

Comment: still did the same thing even when i did not bind to the edit templete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, Derek was right. It had to do with the Binding Data on postback in page load. I binded the data every time instead of just the first time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your grid view row updating event add the following condition

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit )
 {


    int key = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    Label CompanyID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCompanyID");

    TextBox thisIssueDate = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtIssueDate"));

    TextBox NoticeIntentResponseDue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNoticeIntentResponseDue");

    Response.Write(NoticeIntentResponseDue.Text + " " + thisIssueDate.Text);
    Response.End();

    TextBox DeadlineForQuestions = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDeadlineForQuestions");

    TextBox BidsDue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBidsDue");

    TextBox ShortlistNotice = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtShortlistNotice");

    TextBox FinalSelection = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFinalSelection");
    }  
  }
```

Update:
the problem looks like that you have also bind your Edit Item template columns with the data from data table, and when you are getting the data in the code behind you are not getting the updated data which the user updates in edit mode and u still getting the old data. `If you remove the Binding from the Edit Item Template feilds then your code will work.`

Comment: still did the same thing even when i did not bind to the edit templete

Comment: do you add this codition `if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit )` ?

Comment: idk why but it was not letting me call e.Row. I am using the following systems- using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: try this add this event to your page `protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Set the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;    
    BindData(); // bind your grid view
  }`

Comment: try this to get reference of textbox ` TextBox t = (TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0]); or TextBox t = (TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[1]);` for all controls